TS property decorator into React prop
Basically I want to be able to define a controller class for a react component and specify props with a decorator and then extract these decorated properties as props for a component. So that the usage would look like the following (note it just an illustration of the problem):

class Props {

    @Prop()

    a: string:



    @Prop()

    b: number;

}



const A = withProps((this: Props) => {

    return <div>{this.a}</div>;

}, Props);



const B = () => {

    // error: properties a and b are missing

    return <A />;

};



const C = () => {

    // error: cannot assign boolean to number 

    return <A a="test" b={false} />;

};



const D = () => {

    // no errors

    return <A a="test" b={123} />;

};


Reading the Internet I start to think it's impossible but how angular an vue worked this problem around then? Probably there's a library, or maybe you have an idea/experience, or maybe just a good enough idea that would let me achieve similar DX. Any idea is appreciated
I tried chatgpt and tried reflect-metadata
